# how to declare member function using template? (not template class)

Tags: c++, class, templates

I want to declare a template member function in the class.
As i know, we can declare that below case1.
**But it will make several classes, but i want to make only one class.**
I will not use the template to set member variable. I will use that only for parameter of member function. I want  to make template function which can handle vary types in one class instance. 
So, is there any way to make template function in the one class?

```
//case1, standard template function
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class A{
     public:
       void f(T n){
         cout << n <<endl;
       }
};

int main(){
    A<int> a1;
    a1.f(1);
    A<float> a2;
    a2.f(0.1);
}

//case2, i want to make member function which can receive vary type.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
      public:
        template <typename T>
        void f(T n){
           cout << n <<endl;
        }
}

int main(){
   A a();
   a.f(1);
   a.f(0.1);
}
```

Comment: This `A a();` is declaration of function (read more about [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) in c++), you want `A a;`.

Comment: Have you tried? What problems did you run into?

Comment: Sorry for confusing. It looks like there was some misunderstanding about constructor, not template. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me after fixing a couple minor typos:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
      public:
        template <typename T>
        void f(T n){
           cout << n <<endl;
        }
};

int main(){
   A a;
   a.f(1);
   a.f(0.1);
}
```

> $ g++ main.cc
>
> ./a.out
>
> 1
>
> 0.1

Comment: Sorry for confusing. It looks like there was some misunderstanding about constructor, not template. Thanks